# Programmatically obtaining the vendor ID, product ID of a USB device on a Linux platform

Tags: c, usb, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to write a simple device driver, in which I am suppossed to get the Vendor ID and Product ID programmatically. Having gone through almost all the necessary header files, I have come to a conclusion that I can access the vendor ID, product ID, and manufacturer details of the [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) device through a structure: `struct usb_device{}` which has a member `struct usb_device_descriptor{}`. This nested structure has `idVendor, idProduct` and `iManufacturer` and some other members.

But somehow, for some reason I am unable to access these members, so when I do a `dmesg` after inserting my module, it prints some garbage values. I would be glad to receive help or hints or any response. Following is the code that I have written so far:

P.S.: Necessary inclusions have been made.

Having gone through almost all the necessary header files, I know that I can access the vendor ID, product ID, and manufacturer details of the USB device through a structure: `struct usb_device{}` which has a member `struct usb_device_descriptor{}`. This nested structure has `idVendor, idProduct` and `iManufacturer` and some other members.

```
//*******************************************

struct usb_device udev;

struct usb_bus *bus;
ssize_t ret;

static int __init usb_fun_init(void)
{
    int result;
    __le16 idVendor = 0;
    __le16 idProduct = 0;
    __u8 iManufacturer = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in init\n");
    list_for_each_entry(bus, &usb_bus_list, bus_list){

    printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Begins ****************");
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nVendor ID = %d", udev.descriptor.idVendor);
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nProduct ID = %d", udev.descriptor.idProduct);
    printk(KERN_INFO "\nManufacturer = %s", udev.descriptor.iManufacturer);

    return 0;
}

static int __exit usb_fun_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in exit\n");
}

module_init(usb_fun_init);
module_exit(usb_fun_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Are you sure you need kernel module? Maybe this would be simpler to work with that device in userspace?

Comment: @peterSmith : Thank you for kind reply. But Sir, I have to implement this in kernel-space only. I have tried doing it in user-space using libusb. And, It works absolutely fine over there. Where I am getting issues is in kernel-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, the above is the full code for your kernel module. Anyway you are using correct structs and vendor ID, Device ID will be available in device descriptor. [Refer](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) for more details about descriptors.

I suggest you to refer kernel code [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/misc/usbtest.c).

**Update 1:**

---

The following program will give you information about HUBs available in system. usb_hub_for_each_child macro is not supported in 3.2.0 kernel version, but supported in latest 3.7.x versions.

`usb_bus_list` is declared in `#include <linux/usb/hcd.h>`.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/hcd.h>
#include <linux/list.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int ourinitmodule(void)
{

int chix = 0;
struct usb_device *dev, *childdev = NULL;
struct usb_bus *bus = NULL;

list_for_each_entry(bus, &usb_bus_list, bus_list)
{
   printk("\n USB Bus : %d", bus->busnum);

   dev = bus->root_hub;

   printk("\n Vendor Id:%x, Product Id:%x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor, dev->descriptor.idProduct);
#if 0 //usb_hub_for_each_child macro not supported in 3.2.0, so trying with 3.7.6.
   usb_hub_for_each_child(dev, chix, childdev)
   {
        if(childdev)
        {
           printk("\n Vendor Id:%x, Product Id:%x\n", childdev->descriptor.idVendor, childdev->descriptor.idProduct);
        }
   }
#endif

}    

printk(KERN_ALERT "\n Hello Jay, Welcome to sample application.... \n");

return 0;
}

void ourcleanupmodule(void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "\n Hello Jay, Thanks....Exiting Application. \n");
return;
}

module_init(ourinitmodule);
module_exit(ourcleanupmodule);
```

Output is

```
USB Bus :4
Vendor Id:1d6B, Product Id:3
USB Bus :3
Vendor Id:1d6B, Product Id:2
USB Bus :2
Vendor Id:1d6B, Product Id:2
USB Bus :1
Vendor Id:1d6B, Product Id:2
```

Comment: After spending a few time exploring header files, I got it to work.

Comment: No Sir, Not yet. I tested it on linux-2.6.34-12-driver-labs

Comment: @PrasadTandale, Welcome to SO. I suggest you to use name, instead of sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few time exploring header files, I got it to work. It was simple, just that I couldnt visualize what was happening and how it was happenning. I would love to thank all the people who posted/replied to it. Here is the updated sample code, so that someone like me who is newbie could just refer it. Its not at all a perfect reference though, I would love it if someone comes up with suggestions and modifications. Thank You!

```
struct usb_device udev;  

struct usb_bus *bus;  
ssize_t ret;  
static int __init usb_fun_init (void)  
{  
    int result;  
    __le16 idVendor = 0;  
    __le16 idProduct = 0;  
    __u8 iManufacturer = 0;  
    __u8 iSerialNumber = 0;  


    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in init\n");  
    list_for_each_entry(bus, &usb_bus_list, bus_list)
    {  
        printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Begins ****************");  

        printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iSerialNumber);  
        //printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iManufacturer);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->manufacturer);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product = %s", bus->root_hub->product);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %s", bus->root_hub->serial);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "\nManufacturer = %s", udev.bus.iManufacturer);         
    }     
    return 0;  
}  

static void __exit usb_fun_exit (void)  
{  
    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in exit\n");  
}  

module_init(usb_fun_init);  
module_exit(usb_fun_exit);  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```