# Android send AT-commands to USB GSM modem

Tags: android, linux, modem, at-command, usb-otg

I've installed Kali Linux (linuxonandroid project) on my Galaxy Nexus. When attaching the GSM modem (Huawei E169) via OTG cable it only gets detected as a storage device (checked with dmesg). On a real Linux computer the device gets detected as a storage device and modem as well (ttyUSB0). Therefore it's possible to send at-commands to it using minicom.

I disabled the CD-drive (storage device) with the the computer executing this command: AT^U2DIAG=0. The device still won't get detected as a modem.

Is there anything else I can do in order to get this working?

Comment: I haven't done this, but.....What devices (identified by VID/PID, e.g.12d1 1d01) do you see when you put it into modem mode with AT^U2DIAG=0?  What happens if you set it to AT^U2DIAG=1 (modem and storage modes)?

Comment: How do I get the VID/PID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722392/programmatically-obtaining-the-vendor-id-product-id-of-a-usb-device-on-a-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629242/linux-kernel-check-vid-pid-number can help with that, I think.

Comment: lsusb gives me: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem. Doesn't matter if in modem or storage mode.

Comment: I think 12d1:1003 is the storage device.  Can you use these instructions to expose the modem device manually? : https://wiki.debian.org/Huawei/E220