# Modifying a Kernel Space Function in openSUSE-11.3

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, enumeration, libusb-1.0

I have been working on a K-space USB driver for learning purposes.

As far as I have studied the Kernel Space Source files that are included during the time when the USB driver is performing its routines, I have found `announce_devices()` is the function which prints the information of the all USB devices connected over the bus.

I plugged in a USB device (a [BeagleBoard-xM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBoard-xM), in which I have set Product ID and Vendor ID and other descriptors and all of them are verified in User-Space using [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) code), started the computer. When I did a `dmesg`, I was expecting to see my device. But it didn't show up. Then I ran the `libusb` code that I have written, it shows the device.
Due to this, I assume that my device is being enumerated normally.

Question #1: If the libusb code is working perfectly alright, that must be going wrong with the module that I have inserted, right? The code is shared below. (This code is taken as an answer in Stack Overflow question *[Programmatically obtaining the vendor ID, product ID of a USB device on a Linux platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722392)* I had written back in January, and it worked fine then). So is my driver working fine? I have rebuild the kernel a number of times (for a number of dynamic modules) after implementing the above code.

Question #2: Can I modify the Kernel-Space function `announce_devices()` and rebuild the kernel on my machine and verify?

P.S.: Necessary inclusions have been made.

Having gone through almost all the necessary header files, I know that I should be (and I was last time around ) able to access the vendor ID, product ID, and manufacturer details of the [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) device through a structure: `struct usb_device{}` which has a member `struct usb_device_descriptor{}`. This nested structure has `idVendor, idProduct` and `iManufacturer` and some other members.
//*******************************************

```
struct usb_device udev;

struct usb_bus *bus;
ssize_t ret;
static int __init usb_fun_init (void)
{
    int result;
    __le16 idVendor = 0;
    __le16 idProduct = 0;
    __u8 iManufacturer = 0;
    __u8 iSerialNumber = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in init\n");
    list_for_each_entry(bus, &usb_bus_list, bus_list)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Begins ****************");

        printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iSerialNumber);
        //printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iManufacturer);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->manufacturer);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product = %s", bus->root_hub->product);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %s", bus->root_hub->serial);
        printk(KERN_INFO "\nManufacturer = %s", udev.bus.iManufacturer);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit usb_fun_exit (void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in exit\n");
}

module_init(usb_fun_init);
module_exit(usb_fun_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Yes you can. Was there more to the question?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Sir, please see the edit. I have added the code which was written by me only, and the post was also posted by me