# How to access USB bus number from Linux device driver?

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I have two identical USB devices connected to different USB host controllers. Sometimes devices initialization order changes spontaneously breaking devices enumeration. Is there a way to get USB bus number in device driver (it would be enough for implementing of correct initialization) like it is done in user space with lsusb?

Comment: Not perfectly clear what you are asking but browse in sys-fs, maybe you find something what you need. (e.g. in `/sys/bus/usb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the decision. The task was to get USB bus number in kernel module, the similar task was found at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722392/programmatically-obtaining-the-vendor-id-product-id-of-a-usb-device-on-a-linux). It was necessary to get a bus->busnum member of usb_device structure in the driver init function:

```
struct usb_device *usbdev;
struct usb_bus *mybus;
usbdev=interface_to_usbdev(pusb_intf);
mybus=usbdev->bus;
printk("USB Bus number is %d\n",mybus->busnum);
```