# Programmatically obtaining the vendor ID, product ID of a USB device on Linux 5.4

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am currently trying to list all usb devices that are connected to a Linux system, the code will be running in the kernel, as an LSM. The lsm code is known good.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722392/programmatically-obtaining-the-vendor-id-product-id-of-a-usb-device-on-a-linux) question but it was asked six years ago.

The answer to the question suggested using the following code:

```
struct usb_device udev;  

struct usb_bus *bus;  
ssize_t ret;  
static int __init usb_fun_init (void)  
{  
    int result;  
    __le16 idVendor = 0;  
    __le16 idProduct = 0;  
    __u8 iManufacturer = 0;  
    __u8 iSerialNumber = 0;  


    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in init\n");  
    list_for_each_entry(bus, &usb_bus_list, bus_list)
    {  
        printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Begins ****************");  

        printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iSerialNumber);  
        //printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iManufacturer);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->manufacturer);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Product = %s", bus->root_hub->product);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %s", bus->root_hub->serial);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "\nManufacturer = %s", udev.bus.iManufacturer);         
    }     
    return 0;  
}  

static void __exit usb_fun_exit (void)  
{  
    printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in exit\n");  
}  

module_init(usb_fun_init);  
module_exit(usb_fun_exit);  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

However, the compilation errors out. From what i can see, the kernel structures have changed, i have poked about the header files, and the only likely candidate i can see is `usb_bus_id` as it has the same method signature, and return type. However this does not work either. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list_for_each_entry` macro has been replaced with `idr_for_each_entry` for listing USB devices connected to they system.

The following code enumerates USB devices and any children connected to a system with a Linux kernel. The answer code takes the form as a kernel module, but could easily be ported to an LSM.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/hcd.h>
#include <linux/list.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

 struct usb_device udev;  
 struct usb_bus *bus;  
 ssize_t ret;

 static int __init usb_fun_init (void)  
 {  
     int id;
     int chix;
     struct usb_device *dev, *childdev = NULL;

     printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in init\n"); 
     mutex_lock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);
     idr_for_each_entry(&usb_bus_idr, bus, id)
     {  
         printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Begins ****************");  

         printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idVendor);  
         printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.idProduct);  
         printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %x", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iSerialNumber);  
         //printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->descriptor.iManufacturer);  
         printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", bus->root_hub->manufacturer);  
         printk(KERN_INFO "Product = %s", bus->root_hub->product);  
         printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %s", bus->root_hub->serial);                   

         dev = bus->root_hub;
         usb_hub_for_each_child(dev, chix, childdev)
         {
             if(childdev)
             {

                 printk(KERN_INFO "***************** Child device ****************"); 

                 usb_lock_device(childdev);
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Vendor ID = %x", childdev->descriptor.idVendor);  
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Product ID = %x", childdev->descriptor.idProduct);  
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %x", childdev->descriptor.iSerialNumber);  
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Manu = %s", childdev->manufacturer);  
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Product = %s", childdev->product);  
                 printk(KERN_INFO "Serial Number = %s", childdev->serial);  
                 usb_unlock_device(childdev);
             }
         }

     }
     mutex_unlock(&usb_bus_idr_lock);   
     return 0;  
 }

 static void __exit usb_fun_exit (void)  
 {  
     printk(KERN_INFO "\n************************************ in exit\n");  
 } 

 module_init(usb_fun_init);
 module_exit(usb_fun_exit);
```

Sample output:

```
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505160] ***************** Begins ****************
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505161] Vendor ID = 1d6b
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505161] Product ID = 2
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505161] Serial Number = 1
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505162] Manu = Linux 5.0.0-23-generic ehci_hcd
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505163] Product = EHCI Host Controller
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505163] Serial Number = 0000:02:03.0
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505164] ***************** Child device ****************
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505165] 
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505165]  Vendor Id:26bd, Product Id:9917
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505165] Vendor ID = 26bd
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505166] Product ID = 9917
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505166] Serial Number = 3
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505166] Manu =         
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505167] Product = USB DISK 2.0
Feb 29 03:13:46 ubuntu kernel: [ 2743.505167] Serial Number = 070172966462EB10
```